# Facebook Custom App Requests Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, apprequests

I would like to implement my own version of the facebook apprequest dialog, how can i use the FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', display:'iframe',message:'xxxxx'}, function(r){}); so it doesnt display on the page and I can use the friendlists so I dont have to implement my own list

Thanks
Graeme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you can't! (this is due to cross-domain policy, since Requests Dialog will be displayed in `iframe` and it's content not really will be accessible)

But you can imitate something that will look alike with [jQuery Facebook Multi-Friend Selector](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector) or implement it in other ways by requesting user's friends details via Graph API call to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, looks like it will do the job nicely!